# texttooltip not shown for a button. (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

I have coded a button with a texttooltip, but tooltip is not shown when hovered over. Button is visible and clickable.
Why is my tooltip not shown for a button ?

I have the following code in my ApplicationAdapter.create() :

```
    TextButton textButton = new TextButton("The Button", skin);
    textButton.addListener(new TextTooltip("This is the tip ! Why it is not shown ?", skin));
    textButton.setPosition(300,100);
    stage.addActor(textButton);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

*** UPDATE ***

I was wrong. It shows the tooltip, but only after 5 seconds so I thought it is not working. Is there a way to fasten the popup ? How would you do an immediate popup ? Using a window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextTooltip` has a Constructor where you can give a `ToolptipManager`.

In the `TooltipManager` you have a function `instant()` after calling this method the Tooltip will appear instantly.
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TooltipManager.html

Here is an Example of an immediately appearing Tooltip:

```
TextButton textButton = new TextButton("The Button", skin);
TooltipManager tooltipManager = new TooltipManager();
tooltipManager.instant();
textButton.addListener(new TextTooltip("This is the tip ! Why it is not shown ?", tooltipManager, skin));
textButton.setPosition(0,0);
textButton.setSize(5,5);
stage.addActor(textButton);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```